# Is there actually a situation where NameNotFoundException is thrown

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am using the following code to get the package name:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
try {
    pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The documentation states:

> This exception is thrown when a given package, application, or
>   component name cannot be found.

Since this is a critical part of my app, in what situation can this actually happen?

Comment: The way you're calling it, it probably won't/can't throw an exception, but `.getPackageInfo( "SillyMadeUpName", 0 )` probably would!

Answer (score 0):

This is needed in some situation

user can use any package name even non exist on device so exception is needed if package not exist and user try to check it.

Just for an example one of my project was involving following scenario where this was helpful.
I we have service which check for particular android app on regular interval that app exist or not if exist then launch it else just ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You create a application where you save all the installed application in the device . after certain time
 you delete some or one  application from device. And open your application and there you want to retrieve package information from saved package list . You may get this exception.